# Historiography of the Ship of Theseus

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, paradox, identity, ship-of-theseus

Does anybody know of a historiography or review of the discussion of the idea of the Ship of Theseus and things related thereto (I suppose this might also include Alan Gibbard's discussion of the Lumpl-Goliath problem). Failing an actual historiography - or perhaps in addition to it - what are some key references on this?

Comment: See chapter 2 in [Metaphysics of Identity by Gallois](https://books.google.com/books?id=y2R9DAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (I am not entirely sure what "historiography" means in this context). Also, SEP has [Identity Over Time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-time) article with a very long bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote my dissertation on this! The ship of Theseus is just one example of a broader problem called the problem of material constitution, the literature on which is enormous.

As far as the history of the problem:

The ship case is first mentioned by Plutarch, in his *Parallel* *Lives*. And the general problem of identity over time is a topic among stoic philosophers in the Hellenistic period (inc. Chrysippus, IIRC.)

The problem is resurrected in early modern philosophy by Hobbes in a work known as the *de* *corpore*.

For a nice collection of contemporary papers on these issues see the collection called *Material* *Constitution* by Michael Rea.